# Is there a way to update the quickfix entries after running cdo/cfdo?

Tags: quickfix

I usually find myself running pattern replacements on the results of `vim-fugitive`'s `Ggrep`

```
:Ggrep someFunctionName
:cfdo %s/someFunctionName/someOtherName/g | update
```

And that works great but I can still see `someFunctionName` on the quickfix matches.

I know the quickfix gets those values from another function and it doesn't keep track of the actual files, but I'm wondering if there's a way to read the locations and refresh them with the new content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way, but this is how I would do it:

```
call setqflist(map(getqflist(), 'extend(v:val, {"text":get(getbufline(v:val.bufnr, v:val.lnum),0)})'))
```

Basically use `getqflist()` to get each Quickfix line. Using `getbufline()` to get each newly updated line. Then update the quickfix list via `setqflist()`.

Note: This relies on `getbufline()` which requires the buffer to be loaded to get a line back properly (`:cfdo` should load the buffers).

For more help see:

```
:h setqflist()
:h getqflist()
:h map()
:h extend()
:h getbufline()
:h get()
:h :call
```

Comment: That's awesome stuff, thank you.

I don't even need to worry about opening the buffers, `cfdo` already does that for me.

I'll use your answer in this custom command: `command! UpdateQF call setqflist(map(getqflist(), 'extend(v:val, {"text":get(getbufline(v:val.bufnr, v:val.lnum),0)})'))`

That way I can do: `:cfdo %s//something/g | update | UpdateQF`

Comment: Using `UpdateQF` inside `cfdo %s//something/g | update | UpdateQF` is creating a new quickfix list for every file. I imagine this could make quickfix list history useless. May want to do it as a separate command after the executing your `:cfdo` command.